# Module fails dependency check in python script

Tags: ros, python, genmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I attempt to install a module I just built into ROS, it fails to 'find' a required package  because of an error in the associated check_deps.py file. The dependency it is trying to find is package genmsg, which is in fact installed (I even reinstalled, just in case). The Python file genmsg_check_deps.py is producing a Python error very early, during start-up, at the line:
from genmsg import EXT_MSG, EXT_SRV, MsgContext
claiming that there is no module named genmsg.

But of course this Python file itself is in lib/genmsg

We are using ROS Jade

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228456/module-fails-dependency-check-in-python-script/) by [sarima](https://answers.ros.org/users/26197/sarima/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-03-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jackie](https://answers.ros.org/users/23055/jackie/) on 2016-03-07**:
Did you include genmsg in your package.xml as a build_depend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out to have been operator error. I was using sudo to do the install, which clears the environment variables setup by setup.bash.

---

Originally posted by [sarima](https://answers.ros.org/users/26197/sarima/) with karma: 16 on 2016-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0